# Multi media timer works fine in release mode but not on debug mode

Tags: c, debugging, timer, static, release

I'm trying to use mmTimer with a callback function, which is a static `CALLBACK` function.
I know that a static function cannot call a non-static function, thanks to you all guys, except from the case where the static function gets a pointer to an object as an argument.
the weird thing is that my timer works fine in release mode, and when I try to run it in debug mode there is this unhandeled exception that pops up and breaks the program down.

```
void  CMMTimerDlg::TimerProc(UINT uID, UINT uMsg, DWORD dwUser, DWORD dw1, DWORD dw2)
{
    CMMTimerDlg* p = (CMMTimerDlg*)dwUser;
    if(p)
    {
        p->m_MMTimer += p->m_TimeDelay;
        p->UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
}
```

my questions are : - is there any way to resolve this problem? - If this error occurs on debug mode, who ensures me that it wouldn't happen once i release the program?

there is where the program stops:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
void CWnd::AssertValid() const
{
    if (m_hWnd == NULL)
        return;     // null (unattached) windows are valid

    // check for special wnd??? values
    ASSERT(HWND_TOP == NULL);       // same as desktop
    if (m_hWnd == HWND_BOTTOM)
        ASSERT(this == &CWnd::wndBottom);
    else if (m_hWnd == HWND_TOPMOST)
        ASSERT(this == &CWnd::wndTopMost);
    else if (m_hWnd == HWND_NOTOPMOST)
        ASSERT(this == &CWnd::wndNoTopMost);
    else
    {
        // should be a normal window
        ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));

        // should also be in the permanent or temporary handle map
        CHandleMap* pMap = afxMapHWND();
        ASSERT(pMap != NULL);
```

when it gets to pMap it stops at that assertion!!!!

here is the static CALLBACK function

```
static void  CALLBACK TimerProc(UINT uID, UINT uMsg, DWORD dwUser, DWORD dw1, DWORD dw2);
```

here is how I set the timer

```
UINT unTimerID = timeSetEvent(m_TimeDelay,1,(LPTIMECALLBACK)TimerProc,(DWORD)this,TIME_PERIODIC);
```

Comment: How do you set the timer up? What is the call stack at exception position?

Comment: @Roman R 
UINT unTimerID = timeSetEvent(m_TimeDelay,1,(LPTIMECALLBACK)TimerProc,(DWORD)this,TIME_PERIODIC);

Comment: Are you on 32 bit platform? DWORD cannot be used a s pointer on 64-bit.

Comment: no I work on 64bits 
but it doesn't matter it doesn't work on both platforms

Comment: @RomanR   
// should be a normal window
  ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));

  // should also be in the permanent or temporary handle map
  CHandleMap* pMap = afxMapHWND();
  ASSERT(pMap != NULL);

Comment: Can you update the question to include relevant information? Are you setting up from `CMMTimerDlg` method? Is there `_stdcall` specifier at all on your callback method? What is the exception exactly? Yeah we can guess, but you don't need us do it if you have the details. You have **edit** link above to put everything onto question, nicely formatted.

Comment: @RomanR.When it gets to that point it goes off and stops the program.

Comment: @RomanR. on the edit how the timer is called as well in the end.

Comment: Your assertions don't make sense to me (possibly they are good and just unclear from these snippets). I thought it might so happen that code and the callback themselves are good, but the assertions are not. Since there is a limit on actions allowed from the callback, an assertion failure might be fatal for your application. You might want to change assertions to tracing to investigate your code.

Comment: @RomanR. the assertions are from _wincore.cpp_ which is a windows cpp file.
what I dont understand is that this assertion only makes problem with a call to a protected method (UpdateDate()) from CMMTimerDlg inside a static function.

Comment: @RomanR. When I debugged the program, it works fine until it get to _UpdateData(FALSE)_ there it stops at the _ASSERT(pMap!=NULL)_ pointer

Comment: My guess is that you are not allowed to do `UpdateData` from there. Well, more specifically you are not allowed to use some APIs, which are effectively used internally. Read on up what you are allowed to here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @RomanR. thank you very much for your help and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: would you please put it as an answer

Comment: Did you check that commenting `UpdateData` (or otherwise source of assertions) removes the issue on Debug configuiration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that multimedia timer API unlike many other has restrictions on what you are allowed to do inside the callback. You are basically [not allowed much](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and what you are allowed is to update internal structures, do some debug output, and set an synchronization event.

> Remarks
>
> Applications should not call any system-defined functions from inside
>   a callback function, except for PostMessage, timeGetSystemTime,
>   timeGetTime, timeSetEvent, timeKillEvent, midiOutShortMsg,
>   midiOutLongMsg, and OutputDebugString.

Assertion failures start display message boxes which are not allowed and can eventually crash the process. Additionally, windowing API such as `IsWindow` and friends are not allowed either and are the first place cause leading further to assertion failures.

The best here is to avoid using multimedia timers at all. In most cases you have less restrictive alternate options.

Answer (score 1):

It only *looks* like your code works in the Release build, it will not assert() that you are doing it right.  And you are not doing it right.

The callback from a multi-media timer runs on an arbitrary thread-pool thread.  You have to be *very* careful about what you do in the callback.  For one, you cannot directly touch the UI, that code is fundamentally thread-unsafe.  So you most certainly cannot call UpdateData().  At best, you update a variable and let the UI thread know that it needs to refresh the window.  Use PostMessage().  In general you need a critical section to ensure that your callback doesn't update that variable while the UI thread is using it to update the window.

The assert you get in the Debug build suggests more trouble.  Looks like you are not making sure that the timer can no longer callback when the user closes the window.  That's pretty hard to solve cleanly, it is a fundamental threading race.  PostMessage() will already keep you out of the worst trouble.  To do it perfectly clean, you must *prevent* the window from closing until you *know* that the timer cannot callback anymore.  Which requires setting an event when you get WM_CLOSE and not call DestroyWindow.  The timer's callback needs to check that event, call timeKillEvent() and post another message.  Which the UI thread can now use to really close the window.

Threading is hard, do make sure that SetTimer() isn't already good enough to get the job done.  It certainly will be if the UI update is the only side-effect.  You only need timeSetEvent() when you require an accurate timer that needs to do something that is *not* UI related.  Human eyes just don't have that requirement.  Only our ears do.